# Apache Dynamic reverse proxy

Tags: apache, apache2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I want to create Dynamic reverse proxy in Apache like below:

http://www.gmodules.com/ig/proxy?url=http://gmail.com/

I will pass the website in URL parameter and access that website.
So need help to create virtual host using Apache proxy pass like above mentioned link.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get your answer pankaj.Also i am need of a similar for proxypass url whose port will be dependant on the worker.

Comment: No I didn't get the answer yet, let me know if you found it.

Comment: Ah the answer is when we are using Jk_mod there is no need of proxy pass as it is handled by the jkmod. so i had seperately routed the spring security urls also using the modjk and it worked.